Running Solana RPC node WSL
Anyone knows how to run an rpc Solana node on wsl? So im looking for documentation for Wsl. Not full Linux.
I get the error;
[2024-10-12T13:04:05.078162085Z ERROR solana_net_utils] Received no response at tcp/8899, check your port configuration: timed out waiting on receive operation
